# Are there any ice hockey movies where the team loses the big game?

Tags: analysis

The standard formula for an ice hockey movie is as follows:

1. The team is likely to lose the big game.
2. The team gets inspired to do better.
3. The team wins the big game at the last second.

For instance, all three *Mighty Ducks* movies, *Miracle*, and *Slap Shot* followed this formula. Usually this also involves a defeat at the hands of their rivals, and then a rematch where they win.

Are there any ice hockey movies where the team loses the big game?

Comment: [*Mystery Alaska*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134618)

Comment: Isn't this the standard formula for all sports movies, not just hockey movies?

Comment: Does the southpark parody on excactly this topic count?^^

Comment: @Andrew Oh absolutely. I just figured I'd narrow the scope to one sport.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2377/49).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Mystery, Alaska*** from 1999 does it. They play the New York Rangers.

> [The movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery,_Alaska) is about a fictional small town in Alaska named Mystery, where hockey is the cohesive activity that unites the town. The "Saturday Game" is a weekly event of amateur four-on-four pond hockey played on the open ice of the town's frozen lake. The team consists of ten local townsmen of varying ages and occupations with two goalies and eight skaters publicly scrimmaging each other every Saturday. As there are only ten spots on the team, in order to make room on the roster for the younger up-and-coming town players an older more senior member of the team must be kicked off the team. After an article describing the town and its players appears in Sports Illustrated, a nationally televised exhibition game is scheduled between the NHL's New York Rangers and the hometown favorites in Mystery, Alaska.

The actual game play:

> During the match, the Mystery team take time to settle, but eventually go ahead two goals to nothing in the first period. One of the goals is scored by Stevie, who impresses the commentators with his speed. In the second period however, the Rangers score five unanswered goals. Birdie costs the team a goal through his desire to “go it alone” when he should have passed. Unwilling to accept defeat, Mystery scores two goals in the third period, including one from a pass that Birdie makes instead of shooting for goal himself. As the clock ticks down, Connor has a chance to level the scores, but his shot hits the crossbar, and the game is over, with the score at 5 – 4 to the Rangers. Both the Mystery team and spectators appear completely deflated, until Judge Burns starts clapping for them, after which even the Rangers players applaud them.
>
> The following day the Rangers leave, and it is revealed that both Stevie Weeks and Connor Banks have been given professional contracts and fly out with the Rangers.

Home Town underdogs lost. No Rematch.  ***Fin***.

Of course, there was a mid-game motivational speech. The whole movie is basically point 1 & 2, as no-one really though Mystery had a snowballs chance in hell of beating professional hockey players.